# How to know if elements from a list are in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm currently working on this game, very similar to Road Fighter, the thing is that I need to save the scores of the players, I'm doing this using a .txt file, and then I have to display the top scores. 
I'm trying to do this with the code below, my problem is that I need to match those scores with the player name, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong
By the way, I'm supposed to do this recursively

For example, the function GetSortedScores returns a list like this:

```
[10000, 3424, 788, 225, 177, 125, 95, 90, 80, 50, 3]
```

so what I'm trying to do is asking the original list if the elements of the list above match the scores, if the scores match it should create a list with the name of the player and the respective scores, the result I'm looking for is this:

```
[maicolvn 10000, playerone 3424, mike 788, jake 225, francis05 177, julia 125, playerTwo 95, player3 90, jerome 80, frank 50, luke 3]
```

when I try to run the code to test it python shows me this error

```
  if sortedList == []:
```

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

also this is what my txt file looks like:

```
maicolvn,10000
mike,788
playerTwo,95
jake,225
francis05,177
luke,3
jerome,80
frank,50
player3,90
julia,125
playerone,3424
```

thanks in advance for the help, I'm just getting into this so thanks for the feedback

```
def TopScores():
 list = GetSortedScores()
 return TopAux(ReadFile(),list,[])

def TopAux(originalList,sortedList,newList):
 if sortedList == []:
      return newList
 elif sortedList[0] == int(originalList[0].split(",")[1]):
      return TopAux(originalList,sortedList[1:],[originalList[0].split(",")[0]+originalList[0].split(",")[1]]+newList) """This is supposed to get the the name and score of the player"""
 else:
      return TopAux(originalList,sortedList,newList)

def GetSortedScores():
 return(SortScores(GetBestScores(ReadFile(),[])))

def GetBestScores(list,newList):
 """Get scores from file"""
 if list == []:
      return newList
 elif isinstance(int(list[0].split(",")[1]),int):
      return GetBestScores(list[1:],newList+[int((list[0].split(",")[1]))])
 else:
      return GetBestScores(list[1:],newList)

def SortScores(list):
 """Returns a list of scores in descending order"""
 list.sort(reverse=True)
 return list

def ReadFile():
 """This function reads the file of the scores
 and return the content in a list"""
 path = "TopScores.txt"
 file = open(path)
 content = file.readlines()
 file.close()
 return content
```

Comment: You should spend some time explaining what you tried, what went wrong, and provide examples of input, desired output, etc.

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example of the core of the error

Comment: I think you already provided quite a bit of code, but it would be helpful if you provided an example of a (short) high score text file - now we're left to imagine file from your code, but if your code has a mistake, that mistake figures into how the file is imagined.

Comment: why not use json to store data? In such case you don't even have to sort and compare.

Comment: I'm supposed to use a txt file to store data, I wish I could some other alternatives to store the data but this is a school project and I'm just getting started with python so I don't have that option

Comment: you main mistake is that you sort only scores - you should sort pairs `(maicolvn,10000)`  and then you get names with correct values. If you will keep as list `[(10000, maicolvn), ..}` then you can sort it even with standard `sorted(list, reverse=True)` because it will first compare first values - `1000`, etc. - and when you get two elements with the same score then it will compare names to change order.

Answer (score 1):

You could read your scores like this from the file:

```
path = "TopScores.txt"
scores = list()
with open(path) as f:
    for l in f:
      l = l.strip().split(',')
      l[1] = int(l[1])
      scores.append(l)

print(scores)
print(sorted(scores, key = lambda x: -x[1]))
```

Using the lambda function, you could access the points and sort them instead of the names. It would skip the step of matching points with names afterwards.

Reading your script above, i got a syntax-error in line 9. Didn't make it till your RecursionError. Maybe you could restructure and clean up your code ?

Additionally: 
In case you quite often change your scores during playtime for multiple players, you could store the  `player : score` pairs in a dict `scores = dict()` during runtime of your game. 
This way you could simply access and update the scores simply by: `scores.get(<name>)` or set them via `scores[<name>] = score`.

In case you want them as a sorted list for a high score:

```
sorted([[k,v] for k,v  in scores.items()], reverse = True)
```